# Partial duplication of a line with sed

Tags: sed

How can I use sed to duplicate part of a string?

```
hello foo(ignore this);
hello bar(or that);
hello func(or anything really);
```

with

```
hello foo(x) foo(y)
hello bar(x) bar(y)
hello func(x) func(y)
```

I know I can use & multiple times in the replace statement of sed but I have trouble having the matching pattern & be only what's between hello and (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with `&`:

```
sed 's/(.*/(/; s/[^ ]*(/&x) &y)/' test.txt
```

- Clear out everything after open paren: `s/(.*/(/`
- Then capture function name and open paren as `&` and repeat with `x)` and `y)`: `s/[^ ]*(/&x) &y)/`
- `[^ ]*` is capturing the string of non-space chars before the open paren

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ]* ([^(]*)).*/\1(x) \2(y)/' input_file
hello foo(x) foo(y)
hello bar(x) bar(y)
hello func(x) func(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand how to have two matched patterns in one command

Answer (score 1):

My solution is really not pretty: I remove what I don't want from each line until I only have my function names and then I re-add what I did.  I am sure there must be a more elegant approach:

```
$ more test.txt
hello foo(ignore this);
hello bar(or that);
hello func(or anything really);

$ more test.txt | sed  's/hello //g' | sed 's/(.*$//g' | sed 's/.*/hello &(x) &(y)/g'
hello foo(x) foo(y)
hello bar(x) bar(y)
hello func(x) func(y)
```

Comment: You don't need `g` for any of the replacements, and you can simply string those commands together into one sed invocation: `sed 's/hello //; s/(.*//; s/.*/hello &(x) &(y)/' test.txt`